# Reorient Histogram and Scatterplot with Trend Line

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a dataset that looks similar to the one simulated in the code below. There are two sets of observations, one for those at X=0 and another for those at X>0.

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X1 = np.random.normal(0, 1, 100)
X1 = X1 - np.min(X1)
Y1 = X1 + np.random.normal(0, 1, 100)

X0 = np.zeros(100)
Y0 = np.random.normal(0, 1.2, 100) + 2

X = np.concatenate((X1, X0))
Y = np.concatenate((Y1, Y0))

sns.distplot(Y0, color="orange")
plt.show()

sns.scatterplot(X, Y, hue = (X == 0), legend=False)
plt.show()
```

There are two plots: a histogram with KDE and a scatterplot.

[image]

I want to take the histogram with KDE, rotate it, and orient it appropriately with respect to the scatter plot. I would also like to add a trend line for each respective set of observations.

The ideal result would look something like this:

[image]

How do you do this in python, either using seaborn or matplotlib?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by combining `plt.subplots` with shared y-axis to keep the scale and `sns` plots. For trend line you need some additional computation, but you can use `np` for quick fitting. Here is an example how to achieve your goal, and here is [jupyter notebook](https://github.com/trsvchn/stackoverflow-notebooks/blob/master/histogram-and-scatter.ipynb) to play with.

```py
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Prepare some data

np.random.seed(2020)

mean_Y1 = 0
std_Y1 = 1
size_Y1 = 100

X1 = np.random.normal(mean_Y1, std_Y1, size_Y1)
X1 = X1 - np.min(X1)
Y1 = X1 + np.random.normal(mean_Y1, std_Y1, size_Y1)

# this for computing trend line
Z = np.polyfit(X1, Y1, 1)
Y_ = np.poly1d(Z)(X1)

mean_Y0 = 2
std_Y0 = 1.2
size_Y0 = 100

X0 = np.zeros(100)
Y0 = np.random.normal(mean_Y0, std_Y0, size_Y0)

X = np.concatenate((X1, X0))
Y = np.concatenate((Y1, Y0))

# Now time for plotting

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2,
                        sharey=True,
                        figsize=(10, 5),
                        gridspec_kw={'width_ratios': (1, 2)}
                       )
# control space between plots
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.1)

# set the ticks for y-axis:
axs[0].yaxis.set_tick_params(left=False, labelleft=False, labelright=True)
# if you wish you can rotate xticks on the histogram with:
axs[0].xaxis.set_tick_params(rotation=90)

# plot histogram
dist = sns.distplot(Y0, color="orange", vertical=True, ax=axs[0])

# now we need to get the coordinate of the peak, we need this for mean line
line_data = dist.get_lines()[0].get_data()
max_Y0 = np.max(line_data[0])

# plotting the mean line
axs[0].plot([0, max_Y0], [mean_Y0, mean_Y0], '--', c='orange')
# inverting xaxis
axs[0].invert_xaxis()

# Plotting scatterpot
sns.scatterplot(X, Y, hue = (X == 0), legend=False, ax=axs[1])

# Plotting trend line
sns.lineplot(X1, Y_, ax=axs[1])

# Plotting mean again 
axs[1].plot([0, max(X1)], [mean_Y0, mean_Y0], '--', c='orange')

plt.show()
```

Out:

[image: result]